# Run Acceptance tests as a separate Gradle task

Tags: java, gradle, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl, spek

I am trying to configure `Gradle with Kotlin DSL` for my project. It consists of two modules. **Module A** is a simple `Java 11` application. **Module B** cotains the acceptance tests written in `Kotlin` using `Spek`.

I would like to configure gradle so that `gradle test` does not run the acceptance tests and these tests are run only with task `gradle acceptanceTest`. I tried configuration below with other variations of filters, includes and excludes but with no luck. What am I missing?

```
tasks.withType<Test> {
    println("always printed: configuration phase test")

    useJUnitPlatform()

    filter {
        exclude("acceptance.*")
    }

    doLast {
        println("only printed if executed: execution phase test")
    }

}

val acceptanceTest: Task by tasks.creating(Test::class) {
    println("always printed: configuration phase ac")

    useJUnitPlatform {
        includeEngines("spek2")
    }

    filter {
        include("acceptance.*")
    }

    doLast {
        println("only printed if executed: execution phase ac")
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Filter was unnecessary. I just had the `acceptanceTest` task in the wrong place... After moving to the `acceptance` module it works as expected.